# How can I appeal against deleting a duplicate answer I made of one I accidentally posted in the wrong place?

Tags: support, specific-question, moderation, duplicate-answers

I accidentally wrote the answer to the wrong question, and then I replaced it. Then I wrote the answer to the right question. It was accepted and had two upvotes.

But a moderator deleted it for no reason. The message says that I wrote an exact answer for two different questions. But it is not true. This was absolutely a unique answer.

I believe it was happened because the moderator hadn't realized that I edited the first question and fully replaced its content.

What can I do to get it back?

[First post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75275246/7309962), [Second post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75280536/7309962)

Comment: The cause, by the way, is that the "Duplicate answers" autoflag gives absolutely no indication that the other answer was since modified and that the moderator might need to double-check that.

Answer (score 6):

When the mods see this, they'll probably fix it. For now, delete the answer post that you posted to the wrong question. In the future if this kind of thing happens again, you can raise a custom mod flag (see /help/privileges/flag-posts) telling them what happened.

Comment: Handled now, for the record. The other  post was edited to contain a different answer. Deleting it immediately would've been fine though